# Why are muslims circumcised when Allah created him in that way?

Tags: muslim-practices, circumcision

Allah knows the best. He created human beings as the best creation.

**Question:** If He wanted human to be circumcised then why didn't He make the human circumcised automatically in birth?

Aren't we hurting Him by deforming His best creation?

Comment: I think this is covered here already https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26253/is-circumcision-mandatory-for-non-muslim-if-he-want-to-accept-muslim-faith

Comment: I edited my question. Now I think it is not the duplicate of the question you mentioned.

Comment: In the answer it is mentioned that this is following the sunnah of Ibrahim () so no we don't deform the best creation as it is what Allah recommended us to do!

Comment: The basic answer to why Muslims do it, is because of the sunnah, which are mentioned in the ahadith. *The wisdom* behind it is rather something one only can speculate about. Maybe you could look from an evaluational point of view why human males has foreskin, and then from that argue why we do not need it anymore, therefore the circumcision. But then one must ask questions about if the evolution itself is compatible with ones view of Islam. So this question will be pretty opinion based.

Comment: Since Allah created foreskin, it should have some meaning and requirement, which may be till unknown to us.

Comment: The doctrinal answer is "god said so, and we are not willing to call this 'mutilation'". It's in continuation of the story of Abraham as a sacrifice to god. The historical answer is that this was commonplace in the area where the semitic religions developed; the oldest evidence as far as I know is that the Egyptians started it, it spread from there, the Jews adopted it, and Muhammad continued the development of that brand of religious tradition, so it was incorporated for continuity.

Answer (score 2):

Muslims are circumcised because Allah has made it part of our deen:

Hadith from Sahih Bukhari (https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/106):

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Five practices are characteristics of the
>   Fitra: circumcision, shaving the pubic region, clipping the nails and
>   cutting the moustaches short."

Your objection is not logical as Allah also created us naked, yet you acknowledge that nakedness is immodest and do not say if Allah wanted me to wear clothes then he must have created me with them.

Comment: Clothes add a layer of protection. Use your brain before comparing circumcision with wearing clothes